# How to return rows from left table where condition on right table true on all row without sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have 2 table with this sample data.

Parent

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Childs

| id | p_id | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 6 |
| 7 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | 7 |
| 9 | 3 | 8 |
| 10 | 3 | 9 |

And I want to get rows from parents join with childs and number > 3.

But I want to receive only parent whose condition is correct on all childs, and even if the condition is not correct on one child, the parent should not be returned

And I want to do without subquery

```
SELECT * FROM `parent` 
LEFT JOIN `childs` on `childs`.`p_id` = `parent`.`id` 
WHERE `childs`.`number` > '3'
```

I want to get only parent B with this condition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, GROUP_CONCAT(number ORDER BY number) val
  FROM Parent p JOIN Childs c ON p.id=c.p_id
  GROUP BY p.id, p.title
  HAVING SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',1) > 3;
```

Here's a [fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73467097ef33af1574c76774b5cfa093)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can work

```sql
SELECT *
FROM parent p, child c2
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
          FROM child c1 
          WHERE p.id = c1.p_id AND c1.number >3)  AND  p.id = c2.p_id AND c2.number <=3
```

Comment: OP wants rows from parents join with childs. Not parent only.

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to get rows from parents join with childs and number > 3.

> But I want to receive only parent whose condition is correct on all childs, and even if the condition is not correct on one child, the parent should not be returned

I would recommend:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM Parent p JOIN
     Childs c
     ON p.id = c.p_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.title
HAVING MIN(number) > 3;
```

There is no reason at all to use strings for what you want to do.  It just confuses the logic.

An even more efficient method would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select p.*
from p
where not exists (select 1
                  from childs c
                  where p.id = c.p_id and c.number <= 3
                 );
```